# How to enable non-error Apache log on MAMP

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, mamp

How can I enable non-error server logging on MAMP (or, am I totally blind, and is it already enabled by default?)

So far, I can only find the error logs for Apache, MySQL and PHP in /Applications/MAMP/logs. But I'd like to access the server log (ie, the rawest data that the server processes, all of the HTTP requests that it received/served, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/FAQ/#where-can-i-find-the-log-files

> All log files are stored in: /Applications/MAMP/logs/

The logs need to be enabled on Apache.
In the file `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/https.conf` find the lines

```
#CustomLog logs/access_log combined
```

Please uncomment this line by removing the '#', if you do it Apache will write the access logs into `/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/access_log`.
It may not be what you want, if you want to get the access logs in the same directory as the others logs (`/Applications/MAMP/logs/`) use the absolute path to the file:

```
CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_access_log combined
```

`combined` is a log format, that you can find on a line `LogFormat`

About logs, please note that you can also configure the error logs and the log level.

```
ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"
LogLevel error
```

After doing this, restart your MAMP Apache server.

Answer (score 3):

I had success with adding this to the "Additional parameters for <VirtualHost>"

`CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/mySiteName_access.log" combined`

Comment: This line works fine and is an override of the `CustomLog` present in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

All is explained at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html Use `LogFormat` to define a format, `CustomLog` to define a location.